# Run Configuration JAVA ECLIPSE

Tags: java, eclipse

I just started programming in JAVA. I'm using Eclipse as an IDE. My question is about Run Configuration and defining the Main Class to run. 
Do I need to define the main class each time I want to run an application ?
I have different projects into my workspace, when I want to switch between Projects and run a specific class, Eclipse keeps running the last class I ran instead of the current class. So I need to change it in Run Conf manually each time. Is there a way for Eclipse to detect the class I want to run ?

I hope I could make my point, I'm new in coding syntax and jargon. Thanks.

Comment: If your current class has a main method within, simply right click on the class name for your current class -> Run As... -> Java Application

Comment: Yes, this behavior can be configured in _Window > Preferences: Run/Debug > Launching_ in the _Launch Operation_ section.